# How to build an XDocument with a foreach and LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I can use XDocument to build the following file which **works fine**:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument
(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement(_pluralCamelNotation,
        new XElement(_singularCamelNotation,
            new XElement("id", "1"),
            new XElement("whenCreated", "2008-12-31")
        ),
        new XElement(_singularCamelNotation,
            new XElement("id", "2"),
            new XElement("whenCreated", "2008-12-31")
            )
        )
);
```

**However**, I need to build the XML file by **iterating through a collection** like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument
(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));

foreach (DataType dataType in _dataTypes)
{
    XElement xelement = new XElement(_pluralCamelNotation,
        new XElement(_singularCamelNotation,
        new XElement("id", "1"),
        new XElement("whenCreated", "2008-12-31")
    ));
    xdoc.AddInterally(xelement); //PSEUDO-CODE
}
```

There is **Add**, **AddFirst**, **AddAfterSelf**, **AddBeforeSelf**, but I could get none of them to work in this context.

**Is an iteration with LINQ like this possible?**

## Answer:

I took Jimmy's code suggestion with the root tag, changed it up a bit and it was exactly what I was looking for:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement(_pluralCamelNotation,
        _dataTypes.Select(datatype => new XElement(_singularCamelNotation,
            new XElement("id", "1"),
            new XElement("whenCreated", "2008-12-31")
        ))
    )
);
```

Marc Gravell posted a better answer to this [on this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032314/how-can-i-change-this-stringbuilder-to-xml-code-to-linq-to-xml/1032363#1032363).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need a root element.

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement("Root",
        _dataTypes.Select(datatype => new XElement(datatype._pluralCamelNotation,
            new XElement(datatype._singlarCamelNotation),
            new XElement("id", "1"),
            new XElement("whenCreated", "2008-12-31")
        ))
    )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to use XDocument.Add():

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument
(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));

foreach (DataType dataType in _dataTypes)
{
    XElement xelement = new XElement(_pluralCamelNotation,
        new XElement(_singularCamelNotation,
        new XElement("id", "1"),
        new XElement("whenCreated", "2008-12-31")
    ));
    xdoc.Add(xelement);
}
```

Comment: When I use that code I get "this would create a falsely structured XML document", I tried replacing the variables with "tests" and "test" but same error.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's very very old post but I stumbled across this today trying to solve the same problem. You have to add the element to the Root of the document:

```
xdoc.Root.Add(xelement);
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the simple [Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354061.aspx)?

Comment: I'm guessing the author wants a LINQ solution to this problem, except there doesn't seem to be one. Actually, this is an interesting problem - how to turn an `IEnumerable` into a suitable parameter list =)